XFS block size confused on ubuntu
I format my partition (/dev/sda1) to XFS filesystem with a block size of 64KB (mkfs.xfs -b size=65536 /dev/sda1). The xfs_info shows exactly the bsize but the blkid shows only 4096 bytes. Please help me out. Thank you !!!
Image of xfs_info and blkid

The blocksize of the underlying storage device and the block size of the file system is two different things. Commonly the block size of storage media was 512 bytes, recently this has increased to 4096 bytes or 4k.
You can change the blocksize of xfs; you can't change the block size of the underlying storage.

Yes I did change it but I do not know exactly if it works

What is unclear after reading my answer?
